# Implementation of application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: not found in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, appdelegate, url-scheme

I am using following `SDK's` via `CocoaPod`:

```
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
  pod 'Google/SignIn'
  pod 'CleverTap-iOS-SDK'
```

Every thing `works fine` in `iOS9`.

But when I change my deployment target to `iOS8` the `delegate` method defined in `AppDelegate` `-openUrl` is not being called anymore.

Its not being called for both `Facebook` and `Google Sign In`.

When I Tap on `OK` in facebook's authorization page my app relaunches again no delegate is called giving me this log:

```
  <FIRAnalytics/WARNING> Implementation of application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: 
  not found. Please add the handler into your App Delegate. Class: CleverTapAppDelegateSurrogate.
```

**Note** When I comment this Line my Code works well in both iOS versions.But I need to use Clever tap.

```
 //Clever Tap
  [CleverTap autoIntegrate]; //Cause Issue in FB/G logins
```

What is main cause behind it I am not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Google sign and Facebook are also inserting an app delegate proxy, as per here - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseanalytics/category_f_i_r_analytics_07_app_delegate_08. This seems to conflict with the CleverTap delegate proxy.

So for now please use the manual integration. We'll look into resolving this issue.

Comment: I also have this problem. I'm using iOS XCODE v 8 and Swift 3. In the app delegate "openUrl" has been changed to "open" and there is no [CleverTap autoIntegrate]

Comment: Does this mean we cannot use Facebook login for Firebase?

Comment: can u send me any link regarding manual integration of clever tap

Answer (score 5):

Please use this code in app delegate in xcode 8 ios 10.Its working correctly.I used for google plus integration.

```
public func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool
   {

   return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                         sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                         annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])

    }
```